# How can I configure securityDefinitions for swagger-ui?

Tags: swagger-ui

I've added the latest swagger ui to a project which auto generates the swagger.json definitions but doesn't include the new securityDefinitions object. I want to set up basic auth and have seen various docs about the objects and configs but don't understand where to add my securityDefinitions configs to the API so they are picked up in swagger.json. I also have the complete project source so am wondering if I'm supposed to add them to the swagger-config.yaml and make a custom dist build?